# Detectar linguagem do browser e redirecionar

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou usando Wordpress e queria redirecionar minha página para as versões "/br/","/es/", quando a língua do browser for uma dessas  e quando não for ele ficar na página padrão, que é o ".com".

Tentei usar esse código, mas não funcionou:

```
function idiomaUsuario(){
    $idioma = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2);
    return $idioma; 
}


    function redirecionaPaginaIdioma($idioma){
        switch($idioma){
            case 'pt': //Caso seja português
                header('Location: http://www.seusite.com.br/pt/');
                break;
            case 'es': //Caso seja espanhol
                header('Location: http://www.seusite.com.br/es/');
                break;
            default:
                header('Location: http://www.seusite.com.br/en/');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Não sei se muda alguma coisa fazer isso com PHP ou JS, mas qualquer solução serve.

Obs: Coloquei esse código no começo do Index.php do tema do Wordpress.

Comment: Onde colocou as chamadas dos métodos?

Comment: Nesse código está como métodos, mas quando eu testei eu tirei e deixei direto sem as functions.

Comment: Já tentou usar um plugin? Eu uso Transposh. Muito bom.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Eu acredito que esse Plugin faça a tradução do site, porem eu estou fazendo um site com três línguas diferentes e com **conteúdos diferentes.** Com esse Plugin que você me indicou eu não conseguiria montar páginas diferenciadas para cada língua. (Ou até conseguiria, mas teria que trabalhar com algumas condições, para que certo conteúdo só aparecesse conforme a língua, porem é um site dinâmico, tudo precisa ser facilmente alterado via Wordpress.)

Comment: Ele permite tanto a tradução automática quanto o gerenciamento de conteúdo em outros idiomas. Acho mais fácil usar ele para gerenciar qual o idioma que o usuário quer ver por exemplo na pagina principal e para cada página com idioma diferente criar o site map especifico do idioma usando (ele já vem com alguns prontos como os de bandeirinhas) no permalink o que voce quer. É apenas uma sugestão. Tem suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Meu problema atual, além do redirecionamento(o que já está quase resolvido), é como mudar os menus do wordpress dependendo da linguagem. Não consigo colocar um menu diferente para cada página, mas acredito que isso eu vou tentar fazer alterando o tema, mas esse plugin faria isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31464/discussion-between-marcos-regis-and-giovanni-bernini).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta solução posta na pergunta não dá muito certo pelo modo com que o `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` funciona. Ele retorna uma *string* neste formato:

```
en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
```

que indica a ordem de preferência do usuário pelo parâmetro `q=` (chamado tecnicamente de *quality factor*), e como você pode notar, pode ter mais de uma linguagem (geral ou regionalizada) na lista.

Interpreta-se o seguinte na linha de exemplo: "Eu aceito inglês dos EUA, e se não tiver, inglês "geral" (peso 0.8). Na falta destes, pode ser Português do Brasil (peso 0.6), e por último, Português "geral" (peso 0.4).

O problema é que nada garante que esta lista vai vir na ordem de importância. Eu nunca vi fora de ordem, mas a especificação determina claramente que a ordem é dada pelo *quality factor* e não pela posição textual.

Além disso, pode acontecer da primeira da lista ser uma linguagem que você não tem disponível, mas a segunda ou terceira pode ser que sim. Neste caso, como o código da pergunta pega só a primeira da lista, não tem mesmo como ele resolver seu problema.

Posto isto, vamos à solução.

### Função para fazer o *parse* da string

Com base no que mencionei no começo da resposta, elaborei uma função básica que pode servir de ponto de partida para o que você precisa:

```
$acceptLanguage = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$langs = array();
foreach( explode(',', $acceptLanguage) as $lang) {
    $lang = explode(';q=', $lang);
    $langs[$lang[0]] = count($lang)>1?floatval($lang[1]):1;
}
arsort($langs);
```

Basicamente o que ela faz é quebrar a *string* original pelas vírgulas, usando o `explode`, e guardando num *array* no formato 'linguagem=>peso'. Uma vez feito isto, o `arsort` ordena nossa lista começando pelo peso maior e indo até o menor.

Uma vez feito o *parse*, precisamos ver o que temos disponível para servir ao usuário. Para esta parte, aqui tem uma solução:

```
$ourLanguages = array('pt-BR'=>'pt','pt'=>'pt','es'=>'es');

$choice = 'pt'; //Caso nenhuma outra sirva
foreach($langs as $lang=>$q) {
   if(in_array($lang,array_flip($ourLanguages))) {
      $choice=$ourLanguages[$lang];
      break;
   }
}

header("Location: http://www.example.com/$choice/");
```

O princípio de funcionamento é simples, vamos testando uma a uma das linguas do cliente até encontrarmos uma que sirva. Para resolver por completo o problema, usamos o formato `linguagem do cliente => nosso mapeamento`, assim você pode dizer que `pt-BR` deve ser entendido simplesmente como `pt`, que é a parte que você usa no URL.

Você pode ver um exemplo funcional no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/us1fZh)**.

<sub>Só para constar, tem uma extensão PECL que trata disto, mas eu diria que é mais engessada do que a nossa solução: http://php.net/http_negotiate_language</sub>

Comment: obrigado pela ótima resposta, porém eu não conseguindo fazer o redirecionamento, eu testei com um `echo` e funcionou, porém o  `header("Location: http://www.example.com/$choice/");` parece não ter funcionado. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Erro meu, para caso não funcione o redirecionamento para alguém com está mesma duvida, no Wordpress dentro do `page.php` você precisa colocar o código dentro da primeira tag PHP(Template Name), pois se houver alguma tag html ou algum "echo" ou "print" antes desta função, não vai funcionar.

Comment: @GiovanniBernini temos algumas respostas aqui no SOpt que explicam bem isso, não é só quanto ao location. Todo e qualquer header tem que ser emitido antes do conteúdo da página. É um comentário válido, mais relacionado à natureza do header() do que do problema da linguagem em si. Se eu localizar alguma, link aqui. Daria pra contornar com ob_start(), mas eu acho uma solução meio suja.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um plugin muito bom de tradução para o Wordpress chamado [Transposh](http://transposh.org/).

Com ele é possível:

- Traduzir dinamicamente uma página qualquer do site usando Google, Bing, Yandex entre outr
- usar uma página já existente como tradução de outra
- Marcar para não traduzir um determinado trecho ou mesmo toda a página, evitando a tradução automática
- Editar a tradução diretamente no HTML final do site.
- Exibir bandeiras dos idiomas permitindo o usuario ver o site em qualquer idioma
- Gerar links no estilo dominio/xx/pagina onde xx é a sigla do idioma conforme aparece em HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Mais detalhes em http://transposh.org/pt/faq/

Recomendo também a fazer uma doação caso goste do plugin

Comment: `Usar uma página já existente como tradução de outra` É exatamente isso que preciso, vou dar uma procurada aqui na documentação para saber como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Pode pegar essa configuração usando a classe [Locale](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) da biblioteca [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), que está disponível a partir do php5.3.

```
<?php

echo 'Disponiveis: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] .'<br>';
$lang = substr(Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']), 0, 2);

if($lang === 'pt'){
    echo 'Olá amigo';
}else if($lang == 'es'){
    echo 'Hola amigo';  
}else if($lang == 'en'){
        echo 'Hello friend';
}else if($lang == 'de'){
    echo 'hallo Freund';
}
```

Pode usar o firefox como teste para alterar a preferência de idioma. Acesse o menu Ferramentas>opções> guia conteúdo. Em linguagues mude o idioma deixe no topo por exem espanhol e veja o funcionamento do código.

**[Exemplo - PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xex6-1ztu)**