# Traduzir site automaticamente de acordo com o país do internauta

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber se existe uma função php ou JS que através do IP do visitante possibilitasse traduzir o site automaticamente de acordo com o país do internauta sem precisar que ele escolha o idioma manualmente em um select.

Suponhamos que o meu site fosse visitado por alguém da Inglaterra, então automaticamente o script escolheria o idioma inglês da pasta Lang. Se fosse visitado por alguém da Itália automaticamente o script rodasse o idioma Italiano, para visitantes de Portugal e Brasil rodasse o idioma Português e assim por diante.

Procurei algo do tipo mas não encontrei nada sobre o assunto.

Percebi que nos anúncios do adsense, o google utiliza esta função, pois mesmo que nós brasileiros visitemos um site estrangeiro, os anúncios que o adsense exibe são de campanhas brasileiras. è como se detectasse a localidade do visitante.
E é isso que eu quero, detectar o pais do usuário e criar uma condição como:

```js
Se localidade do visitante é igual à Brasil ou Portugal
Utilizar idioma português
 Se não se localidade  do visitante é igual à EUA ou Inglaterra ou Canadá etc
Utilizar idioma inglês
 Se não se localidade do visitante é igual à Espanha ou Argentina ou México etc
Utilizar idioma espanhol
e assim por diante ...
```

Comment: Pode usar [`navigator.language`](https://jsfiddle.net/reL7juw4/) para pegar a linguagem utilizada no navegador do usuário e então chamar um recurso no servidor que retorna as frases/palavras naquele idioma.

Comment: Relacionados: [Detectar linguagem do browser e redirecionar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97732/91), [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21788/91) e [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15937/91). Tem outras perguntas sobre o assunto, pode procurar pelo termo i18n.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar a linguagem usando JS e a partir daí traduzir seu conteúdo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `$idioma = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2);` para reconhecer o idioma.